# Ввод элементов массива через файл

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы

Нужно прочитать данные из файла с названием input и считать элементы этого файла. Файл находится в папке с программой.В файле первые два числа отвечают за порядок массива, остальные числа-Сами элементы массива. Не получается запись этих элементов, временно заменил на вывод элементов.
Часть Кода программы ниже

```
 if (choice == 2)
 {
    system("cls");
    
    ifstream inf;
    inf.open("input.txt");
    char ch;
    int i=0;
    if (inf.is_open())
    {
        inf.get(ch);
        x = ch;
        inf.get(ch);
        y = ch;
        while (inf.get(ch))
        {
            int i = 0;
            i++;
            if (i > 2)
            {
                cout << ch; //заменил на вывод
            }
            
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Если открытие файла прошло не успешно
        cout << "Файл не найден.";
    }

}
```

Comment: в папке с исходным кодом или в папке с запускаемым файлом? (должен быть в папке с запускаемым файлом, либо нужно правильно указать путь к файлу)

Comment: @Bogdan,Отредактировал

Comment: там где *.exe файл, туда и нужно положить input или указать абсолютный/относительный путь к файлу в строке `fin.open("path/to/file")`

Comment: Спасибо теперь помогло

Comment: @Bogdan, как можно заполнить двумерный массив с помощью файла? В файле находится превые два числа размерность массива, остальные это элементы массива.Спасибо

Comment: это уже похоже на тему для другого вопроса :)